# How to sort strings and numbers in a same array for a datatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, datatable

I am rebuilding a datatable using React with JavaScript so I am sorting some information that includes strings and numbers so I have been trying to implement `array.sort(a, b) => a.toLowerCase > b.toLoweCase... etc` to sort everything, and at some point it works perfectly until I click the button that sorts the numbers because It gives me an error,

And without tolowercase function that specific sort number section works perfectly but the other ones that have strings with uppercase and lowercase don't sort correctly

How can I solve this problem?

```
const useSortableData = (data, config = null) => {
const [sortConfig, setSortConfig] = useState(config);

  const sortedItems = useMemo(() => {
    let sortableItems = [...data];
    if (sortConfig !== null) {
      sortableItems.sort((a, b) => {
    const optionA = a[sortConfig.key].toString().toLowerCase()

    const optionB = b[sortConfig.key].toString().toLowerCase()

    if (optionA < optionB) {
      return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if (optionA > optionB) {
      return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
      });
    }
    return sortableItems;
  }, [data, sortConfig]);

  const requestSort = (key) => {
    let direction = 'ascending';
    if (
      sortConfig &&
      sortConfig.key === key &&
      sortConfig.direction === 'ascending'
    ) {
      direction = 'descending';
    }
    setSortConfig({ key, direction });
  };

  return { data: sortedItems, requestSort, sortConfig };
};
```

Error which I receive when I click the number sort section

> TypeError: a[sortConfig.key].toLowerCase is not a function

More clean code

```
    const optionA = a[sortConfig.key].toString().toLowerCase()

    const optionB = b[sortConfig.key].toString().toLowerCase()

    if (optionA < optionB) {
      return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if (optionA > optionB) {
      return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Does the data contain null or undefined values?

Comment: No, the data is passed correctly in another component.

Comment: Hm, since you mentioned that your data consists of strings and numbers, you might want to convert them to string before using toLowerCase

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I am using react-typescript

Comment: I would first check if the value is a number `Number.isInteger(value)`. If true, convert to string `value.toString()`. But you don't wanna mutate the original values, so create a variable for those converted string and replace those  `a[sortConfig.key]` with the string variables

Comment: @ShawnYap I implemented toString() function but the numbers are not sorting well. For example all the string numbers which start with '1' will be first than others `1, 10 1100, 2, 3 ,4`

Comment: Strings are sorted by comparing individual characters from left to right, so since '2' is greater than the first '1' in 1100 it will be sorted that way. To sort string representations of numbers ordinally, they must all be the same number of characters and left-padded with zero's. So your example would need to be mapped to `"0001", "0010", "1100", "0002", "0003", "0004"` before applying the sorting function.

Comment: @formula-hunter Thank you very much, how would you implement it to my current code?

Comment: It will require a pre-pass to find the longest numeric string. You could do this in a compact way with something like: `let maxLength = Math.max(...sortableItems.filter(val => type of val === 'number').map(val > val.toString().length));`

Comment: Then replace the numeric values with their string representations: `sortableItems = sortable items.map(val => typeof val === 'number' ? val.toString().padStart(maxLength, '0') : val);` After that transformation the numeric strings should sort correctly with the code you've already written.

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. I'm on my phone and it is difficult to write good quality answers, which is why I put this in comments and not as an answer...

Comment: @formula-hunter Do not worry thank you very much for helping me too! Your answer is really useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from comment for sorting alphanumerical data:
Hope you don't mind me cleaning up a little

```js
  const sortedItems = useMemo(() => {
    let sortableItems = [...data];
    if (sortConfig !== null) {
      sortableItems.sort((a, b) => {
        let aString = a.toString().toLowerCase();
        let bString = b.toString().toLowerCase();

        if (sortConfig.direction === 'descending') {
          return bString.localeCompare(aString, 'en', { numeric: true })
        }
        
        // return default as ascending
        return aString.localeCompare(bString, 'en', { numeric: true })
      });
    }
    return sortableItems;
  }, [data, sortConfig]);
```